# how to find a specific set of letters in a block of letters in php

Tags: php, string

I need to extract some words in a set of letters ,          ,

*example*

"gkshgksguvjvjvvjgvjgvjgvgdkgu**STACK**ksbegkbeskbgksebgkbb**OVERFLOW**ghbhjjhvjvjvjvjgvgjvgjvgjvgjvjgvgjvgjvgjvjg**STACK**ksbbb**OVERFLOW**vjvvvgjvgvgjvgjvgjvgjvvsdkgfkdgdgfdsgkhsdgdgfdsgffsdhkg"

1. I want to extract   "**STACK**ksbegkbeskbgksebgkbb**OVERFLOW**"
   from the above text,
2. number of letters between **STACK** and **OVERFLOW** can be vary.
3. if there are more than one **satck**s and **overflow**s in the set
   of
           letters , I want to find them all with the letters inbetween those
           two words ,*(and add them to an array)*

   *each time , the number of letters in between STACK and OVERFLOW can be changed*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: @Winter I need a solution in php, not just to learn about regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$theBlob = "abcSTACKmmmOVERFLOWxyz...";
preg_match_all('/STACK(.*)OVERFLOW/U', $theBlob, $matches);
assert( $matches[0][0] === 'STACKmmmOVERFLOW' );
assert( $matches[1][0] === 'mmm' );
```

CORRECTED: Added `U` modifier to make `.*` non-greedy.

The regular express `/STACK(.*)OVERFLOW/U` has the `U` modifier to make `.*` non-greedy which means it should match the minimal number of characters (if no `U`, `.*` will be greedy and match as much as it can (up to the last "OVERFLOW").

`$matches` will be an array of arrays.  `$matches[0]` is an array of all the full matches.  `$matches[1]` contains an array of all sub-parts in the first set of parenthesis.

See http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7cix-4y38

Note: the `U` modifier makes all repeaters non-greedy.  If you want to mix greedy and non-greedy, you can do `.*?` to make just that one non-greedy.  The regex above would become `/STACK(.*?)OVERFLOW/'`

Comment: Ooops, sorry, I forgot to add "ungreediness" to the regex pattern.  Answer above has been corrected.

Comment: thank you very much !!! it really works :) we need more people like you on this planet :)